# How to expand/flatten pandas dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that on one of its columns, each element is a list.
I would like to flatten it, such that every list element would have a row of it's own.

I managed to solve it with `iterrows`, `dict` and `append`(see below) but it is too slow with my true DF that is large.
Is there a way to make things faster?

I can consider replacing the column with list per element in another format (maybe hierarchical df? ) if that would make more sense.

**EDIT**: I have many columns, and some might change in the future. The only thing i know for sure is that I have the fields column. That's why I used `dict` in my solution

A minimal example, creating a df to play with:

```
import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO("""
id|name|fields
1|abc|[qq,ww,rr]
2|efg|[zz,xx,rr]
"""), sep='|')
df.fields = df.fields.apply(lambda s: s[1:-1].split(','))
print df
```

resulting df:

```
   id name        fields
0   1  abc  [qq, ww, rr]
1   2  efg  [zz, xx, rr]
```

my (slow) solution:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=df.columns)

for _, i in df.iterrows():
    flattened_d = [dict(i.to_dict(), fields=c) for c in i.fields]
    new_df = new_df.append(flattened_d )
```

Resulting with

```
    id name fields
0  1.0  abc     qq
1  1.0  abc     ww
2  1.0  abc     rr
0  2.0  efg     zz
1  2.0  efg     xx
2  2.0  efg     rr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the lists in the `fields` column into multiple columns by applying `pandas.Series` to `fields` and then merging to `id` and `name` like so:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns != 'fields'].tolist() # adapted from @jezrael 
df = df[cols].join(df.fields.apply(pandas.Series))
```

Then you can melt the resulting new columns using `set_index` and `stack`, and then reseting the index:

```
df = df.set_index(cols).stack().reset_index()
```

Finally, drop the redundant column generated by reset_index and rename the generated column to "field":

```
df = df.drop(df.columns[-2], axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'field'})
```

Comment: The first command fails. error is `MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on`

Comment: Yep sorry, I meant to use `join`, which works based off the index values. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Still doesnt work. Here is the result (flattened to one line):
    
    `id name level_2             0
    0   1  abc  fields  [qq, ww, rr]
    1   2  efg  fields  [zz, xx, rr]`

Comment: Also, it looks like the `reset_index` at the end results in an extraneous `level_2` column, which can simply be dropped (i.e. `df.drop('level_2', axis=1, inplace=True)`)

Comment: But that doesn't solves the main issue, which is that the DF is not expanded

Comment: Ah, my answer depends on the fact that `fields` elements are actually lists; when reading in the dataframe with StringIO, each element is actually a string, like `'[qq,ww,rr]'`. Will the 'list' elements always exist as strings that need to be parsed?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo during copy pasting. Your solution works.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numpy` for better performance:

Both solutions use mainly [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).

```
from  itertools import chain

vals = df.fields.str.len()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        "id": np.repeat(df.id.values,vals),
        "name": np.repeat(df.name.values, vals),
        "fields": list(chain.from_iterable(df.fields))})
df1 = df1.reindex_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
print (df1)
   id name fields
0   1  abc     qq
1   1  abc     ww
2   1  abc     rr
3   2  efg     zz
4   2  efg     xx
5   2  efg     rr
```

Another solution:

`df[['id','name']].values` converts columns to `numpy array` and duplicate them by [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), then stack values in `lists` by [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and add it by [`numpy.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html).

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((df[['id','name']].values.
                   repeat(list(map(len,df.fields)),axis=0),np.hstack(df.fields))),
                   columns=df.columns)

print (df1)
  id name fields
0  1  abc     qq
1  1  abc     ww
2  1  abc     rr
3  2  efg     zz
4  2  efg     xx
5  2  efg     rr
```

More general solution is filter out column `fields` and then add it to `DataFrame` constructor, because always last column:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns != 'fields'].tolist()
print (cols)
['id', 'name']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((df[cols].values.
                   repeat(list(map(len,df.fields)),axis=0),np.hstack(df.fields))), 
                   columns=cols + ['fields'])

print (df1)
  id name fields
0  1  abc     qq
1  1  abc     ww
2  1  abc     rr
3  2  efg     zz
4  2  efg     xx
5  2  efg     rr
```

Comment: Thanks. I have many columns, and some might change in the future. The only thing i know for sure is that I have the fields column. Is there a way to refactor your solution, s.t. I won't have to manually type 'id', 'name'? That's why in my solution I used dict()

Comment: Yes, I think second solution is then better. Give me a minute.

Comment: It works and fast. Could you explain in the body the input to the constructor?

Comment: Note that the list is redundant. map(len, df.fields) already returns a list

Comment: Sorry, it isnecessary for python 3, in python 2 you can omit it.

Answer (score 2):

If your CSV is many thousands of lines long, then `using_string_methods` (below)
may be faster than `using_iterrows` or `using_repeat`:

With

```
csv = 'id|name|fields'+("""
1|abc|[qq,ww,rr]
2|efg|[zz,xx,rr]"""*10000)

In [210]: %timeit using_string_methods(csv)
10 loops, best of 3: 100 ms per loop

In [211]: %timeit using_itertuples(csv)
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop

In [212]: %timeit using_repeat(csv)
10 loops, best of 3: 126 ms per loop

In [213]: %timeit using_iterrows(csv)
1 loop, best of 3: 1min 7s per loop
```

So for a 10000-line CSV, `using_string_methods` is over 600x faster than `using_iterrows`, and marginally faster than `using_repeat`.

---

```
import pandas as pd
try: from cStringIO import StringIO         # for Python2
except ImportError: from io import StringIO # for Python3

def using_string_methods(csv):
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep='|', dtype=None)
    other_columns = df.columns.difference(['fields']).tolist()
    fields = (df['fields'].str.extract(r'\[(.*)\]', expand=False)
              .str.split(r',', expand=True))
    df = pd.concat([df.drop('fields', axis=1), fields], axis=1)
    result = (pd.melt(df, id_vars=other_columns, value_name='field')
              .drop('variable', axis=1))
    result = result.dropna(subset=['field'])
    return result


def using_iterrows(csv):
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep='|')
    df.fields = df.fields.apply(lambda s: s[1:-1].split(','))
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=df.columns)

    for _, i in df.iterrows():
        flattened_d = [dict(i.to_dict(), fields=c) for c in i.fields]
        new_df = new_df.append(flattened_d )
    return new_df

def using_repeat(csv):
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep='|')
    df.fields = df.fields.apply(lambda s: s[1:-1].split(','))
    cols = df.columns[df.columns != 'fields'].tolist()
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack(
        (df[cols].values.repeat(list(map(len,df.fields)),axis=0),
         np.hstack(df.fields))), columns=cols + ['fields'])
    return df1

def using_itertuples(csv):
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep='|')
    df.fields = df.fields.apply(lambda s: s[1:-1].split(','))
    other_columns = df.columns.difference(['fields']).tolist()
    data = []
    for tup in df.itertuples():
        data.extend([[getattr(tup, col) for col in other_columns]+[field] 
                     for field in tup.fields])
    return pd.DataFrame(data, columns=other_columns+['field'])

csv = 'id|name|fields'+("""
1|abc|[qq,ww,rr]
2|efg|[zz,xx,rr]"""*10000)
```

---

Generally, fast NumPy/Pandas operations are possible only when the data is in a
native NumPy dtype (such as `int64` or `float64`, or strings.) Once you place
lists (a non-native NumPy dtype) in a DataFrame the jig is up -- you are forced
to use Python-speed loops to process the lists.

So to improve performance, you need to avoid placing lists in a DataFrame.

`using_string_methods` loads the `fields` data as strings:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv), sep='|', dtype=None)
```

and avoid using the `apply` method (which is generally as slow as a plain Python loop):

```
df.fields = df.fields.apply(lambda s: s[1:-1].split(','))
```

Instead, it uses faster vectorized string methods to break the strings up into
separate columns:

```
fields = (df['fields'].str.extract(r'\[(.*)\]', expand=False)
          .str.split(r',', expand=True))
```

Once you have the fields in separate columns, you can use `pd.melt` to reshape
the DataFrame into the desired format.

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id', 'name'], value_name='field')
```

---

By the way, you might be interested to see that with a slight modification `using_iterrows` can be just as fast as `using_repeat`. I show the changes in `using_itertuples`.
`df.itertuples` tends to be slightly faster than `df.iterrows`, but the difference is minor. The majority of the speed gain is achieved by avoiding calling `df.append` in a for-loop since that [leads to quadratic copying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/190597).

Comment: Thanks. I like your approach, but in my case the original data doesn't really come from CSV, so that's not a problem.